# Calmap.yearplot does not mark days without data

Tags: python, calendar, heatmap

I am using `calmap.yearplot` from [Calendar heatmaps from Pandas time series data](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/) for data visualisation. As the documentation said, missing days in the data (its a pd.Series) should be visualized by a special fillcolor.

As you see in figure 1, only days *after* the last day with data is marked in grey (2), other dates (1) aren't marked in grey and got the same color as a day with value=0.

Figure1:

[image]

And here's how it should be visualized:

[image: Figure 2]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and found a workaround by customizing the cmap for values outside of a defined range:

```
#choose cmap to customize    
cmap_custom = plt.cm.Greens

#set color for values outside of range (i.e., NaNs)
cmap_custom.set_under('w') 

#fill NaNs with value outside of range defined by vmin/vmax arguments
calmap.yearplot(series.fillna(-1), vmin=0, vmax=5)
```